# Routing Problem with custom language code on asp.net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, routes

I am attempting to add a custom language code before the controller using asp.net core 3.1, and the language code is not a standard cultural code on C#.

E.g.

**en = English,
tch = Chinese**

So that the outcome should be:

```
localhost/en     -> Go to Home page in English

localhost/tch    -> Go to Home page in Chinese

localhost/       -> Should redirect to localhost/en 

also, there are other controller that need to include the language code as well

localhost/en/blog        -> Go to blog Listing page in English

localhost/blog           -> Redirect to localhost/en/blog and Go to blog Listing page

localhost/en/blog/{id}   -> Go to blog detail page in English

localhost/blog/{id}      -> Redirect to localhost/en/blog/{id}   and Go to blog detail page

localhost/en/event          -> Go to event Listing page in English

localhost/event             -> Redirect to localhost/en/event and Go to event Listing page

localhost/en/event/{id}     -> Go to event detail page in English

localhost/event/{id}        -> Redirect to localhost/en/event/{id}  and Go to event detail page
```

On the startup.cs, I use UseEndpoints for routing on

```
  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                {
                    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                        name: "others",
                        pattern: "{language}/{controller}/{id?}",
                        defaults: new { action = "Index" });

                    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                       name: "default",
                       pattern: "{language}/{controller=Home}",
                       defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
            });
```

Below is my blog controller class:

```
      [Route("{language}/blog")]
        [Route("blog")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string language)
        {
            if (language == null || (!language.Equals("en") && !language.Equals("tch")))
                return  RedirectToAction("Index", new { language = "en" });
.......
        }
```

Above code works fine if I input localhost/en/blog and the language parameter can capture the language from URL, But When I am trying to use RedirectToAction, the language become a Query String localhost/blog?language=en, Just wondering if there is any settings/coding wrong...

Anyone can kindly give me some advise? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is to create a custom route constraint : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#custom-route-constraints